# Configure Eclipse Kepler+ for ANTLR v3 with C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, antlr

How to install and configure any latest Eclipse IDE version to work with ANTLR3 and C++ runtime, to productively work on available C++ ANTLR runtime?
(Or other advise for any other decent IDE for ANTLR3 and C++).

I want to have the most modern Eclipse version to work with,
But would do any normal Eclipse version.
Kepler looks, doesn't support ANTLR plugin for versions greater then 2.7.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254951/antlr-and-eclipse-or-any-decent-ide) relates to ANTLR4 & Java/et al., but ANTLR4 doesn't (yet) support C++. The latest working ANTLR C++ runtime is for ANTLR v3.

Answer (score 0):

So far the C++ runtime is not 100% finished. The debug part is not implemented yet.
If you want to "tune" your grammar in ANTLR IDE you must use Java target.

And then possibly which target to C++

Comment: Do you mean C++ runtime for ANTLR **v3** has problems with debugging?

Comment: Now, I have a translator written using Java, pretty well working,
now I should "tune" its memory usage, and since Java is too greedy for that,
So I will switch to C++ as fast as I can, after configuring the Eclipse IDE

Comment: It has not problems. It's not implemented yet. Also AST generation is not officially supported. It's only available in mine branch https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3. Just beware the implication Java => greedy , C++ effective is not automatic. For example C target is VERY greedy (especially 64bit) because each AST node hold many pointers onto functions. Even C++ target might some problems. The Java target was well maintained over the time, but C target was "overlooked".